# Capture "ls " command into an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to capture the output of the `ls` command to an array.
I tried something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use feature 'say';

use feature "switch";

my $a= system("ls  /media");
my @words = split / /, $a;
my $name = $words[0];
my $name2 = $words[1];
say $name;
```

But, not only it outputs the same string as `$a`, but is limited to 2 elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[system](http://p3rl.org/system) returns the exit status, not the output of the command. Use backticks, `qx{}`, or [readpipe](http://p3rl.org/readpipe) to get the output:

```
# The following lines are equivalent.
my @lines = `ls`;
my @lines = qx{ ls };
my @lines = readpipe 'ls';
```

To get the contents of a directory, it's usually safer (filenames can contain whitespace and newlines) and faster (no shelling out) to run

```
my @files = glob '*';
```

or

```
opendir my $dir, "/path/to/dir" or die $!;
my @files = readdir $dir;
```

Never use `my $a`. `$a` is a special variable used in [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort), lexicalising it might prevent `sort` from working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `readpipe` or its shorthand

```perl
my @lines = `ls /media`;
chomp @lines;
```